# How to Filter Data Array by Week Filter()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently trying to filter my data array by week, I have been able to filter by day quite easily however am struggling with dates between x and y (eg by week).

I have tried setting a start date and end date (today) and then trying to return the dates less than or equal to the start and end dates but am failing.

Data array date format: dd/mm/yyyy (01/01/2000)

The user will select which filter to use (hence switch() ) case 7 being filter by 7 days.

```
computed: {
    appointments: function () {

      var today = new Date();
      var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
      var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();


      var data = this.$store.state.appointments;

      this.filter1_color = "grey";
      this.filter2_color = "grey";

      switch (this.dateFilter) {
        case 0:
        break;

        case 1:
        console.log("case1: " + today)
        return data.filter(word => word.date == today);

        case 7:

        /// WORKING /// (ex. edit)
        var week = [];

        var today = moment();
        var sevenDaysBefore = today.subtract(7, 'days');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          let momentDate = moment(data[i].date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
          let newDate = momentDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY")
          if (momentDate.isBetween(sevenDaysBefore, moment(), null, '[]')) week.push(data[i]);
        }


        return week
        ///

      }


      return data;
    },
```

I need to filter the data to only show items in the array with dates equal to the dates in the last 7 days.

Comment: Can you use a library like moment js?

Comment: @f-CJ I can, I just installed it and it looks handy dandy - still need to find a solution though.

Comment: Yes it is. You need to get as result all the appointments that are in this week or just in the last 7 days?

Comment: @f-CJ Just last 7 days is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use method `isBetween` of moment js library with current date. You can subtract 7 days to current date with `subtract(7, 'days')`.

You can check more about [`isBetween`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) method in moment js library documentation. The third parameter of the method is the granularity, and it seems that in your case it should 'days'

```js
const today = moment();
const sevenDaysBefore = moment().subtract(7, 'days');

console.log('Today is ' + today.format('MMM Do YYYY'));
console.log('Is ' + today.format('MMM Do YYYY') + ' included in the last seven days?');
console.log(today.isBetween(sevenDaysBefore, today, 'day', '[]'));

console.log('Is ' + sevenDaysBefore.format('MMM Do YYYY') + ' included in the last seven days?');
console.log(sevenDaysBefore.isBetween(sevenDaysBefore, today, 'day', '[]'));

const eightDaysBefore = moment().subtract(8, 'days');
console.log('Is ' + eightDaysBefore.format('MMM Do YYYY') + ' included in the last seven days?');
console.log(eightDaysBefore.isBetween(sevenDaysBefore, today, 'day', '[]'));

const oneDayAfter = moment().add(1, 'days');
console.log('Is ' + oneDayAfter.format('MMM Do YYYY') + ' included in the last seven days?');
console.log(oneDayAfter.isBetween(sevenDaysBefore, today, 'day', '[]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Added another answer in case the OP cannot use `moment.js`. However, upvoted and recommended your answer.

Comment: @f-CJ Thanks for that. It gets essentially what I need but I am having trouble implementing it. I have set a for loop to filter them out (see my updated code between /// EDIT /// - but get `TypeError: e[i].date.isBetween is not a function` which is confusing as it works when putting it in its own if statement.

Am I trying to do it the hard way?

Comment: @TimRowley You have to parse `date` to convert it to `moment`. `isBetween` is a moment method. Probably just with `moment(data.date[i], 'DD/MM/YYYY')` you are fine but check documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: I meant `moment(data[i].date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: @f-CJ Wonderful - thanks for that, it makes so much more sense now. I have got it to a working state now which is fantastic, sure will make life easier with Moment JS. (Added working code to OP)

Comment: Awesome, you are more than welcome @TimRowley! See you around.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to or cannot use a library like `moment.js`, and also don't mind an ad-hoc implementation with certain restrictions:

**Note**

*I recommend to use a library for working with `Date` objects, especially when it comes to parsing a string to a date. Too many things can go wrong when doing it by hand. If possible, use the answer of @f-CJ*

These parts allow you to create a `Date` object from a string. However, the resulting `Date` is *always converted to local time* and the string *needs to have a certain formatting* (the one you showed in your question). If you need support *for UTC, this won't work*. Also, it cannot be used to parse a date string with *ISO formatting*.

```js
const OFFSET_TO_UTC = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

function parseDateString (dateString, sep) {
  var parts = dateString.split(sep);
  return parts.map(n => Number(n));
}

function localizeDate (pattern, parts) {
  return pattern.reduce((acc, pat, i) => {
    switch (pat) {
      case 'd':
        return Object.assign(acc, { day: parts[i] });
      case 'm':
        return Object.assign(acc, { month: parts[i] });
      case 'y':
        return Object.assign(acc, { year: parts[i] });
      default:
        return acc;
    }
  }, {});
}

function toDate (localized) {
  return new Date(
    localized.year,
    localized.month - 1,
    localized.day,
    0, 0 - OFFSET_TO_UTC, 0);
}

function parseDate (pattern, sep, dateString) {
  return toDate(localizeDate(pattern, parseDateString(dateString, sep)));
}


// try it:

const dStringUS = '04/04/2019'; // mm/dd/yyyy
const dStringDE = '04.04.2019'; // dd/mm/yyyy

const dateUS = parseDate(['m', 'd', 'y'], '/', dStringUS);
const dateDE = parseDate(['d', 'm', 'y'], '.', dStringDE);

console.log(dateUS);
console.log(dateDE);
```

Based on it, you can write yourself a generic filtering function:

```js
const OFFSET_TO_UTC = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

function parseDateString (dateString, sep) {
  var parts = dateString.split(sep);
  return parts.map(n => Number(n));
}

function localizeDate (pattern, parts) {
  return pattern.reduce((acc, pat, i) => {
    switch (pat) {
      case 'd':
        return Object.assign(acc, { day: parts[i] });
      case 'm':
        return Object.assign(acc, { month: parts[i] });
      case 'y':
        return Object.assign(acc, { year: parts[i] });
      default:
        return acc;
    }
  }, {});
}

function toDate (localized) {
  return new Date(
    localized.year,
    localized.month - 1,
    localized.day,
    0, 0 - OFFSET_TO_UTC, 0);
}

function parseDate (pattern, sep, dateString) {
  return toDate(localizeDate(pattern, parseDateString(dateString, sep)));
}



const data = [{
  value: 0,
  date: '04/05/2019'
}, {
  value: 1,
  date: '04/07/2019'
}, {
  value: 2,
  date: '03/07/2019'
}];

function filterByDatePattern (pattern, sep) {
  return function (date, list) {
    return list.filter(item => {
      var itemDate = parseDate(pattern, sep, item.date);
      return itemDate >= date;
    });
  }
}

const onlyUSUntil = filterByDatePattern(['m', 'd', 'y'], '/');
console.log(onlyUSUntil(new Date(2019, 3, 1), data));
```

Comment: Thanks David, certainly looks a lot harder to implement. Appreciate it :)